# Using F2 key on Thunar side pane tree

Tags: shortcut-keys, 22.10, thunar

I want to use the <kbd>F2</kbd> key on the side pane tree of Thunar file manager (which can be displayed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>). When I select an item (directory or file) on the side pane tree and press <kbd>F2</kbd> this shortcut *does not* work.

There is a **Rename...** option on the right-click menu which is displayed when an item on the side pane tree is selected and right clicked. However, it seems that the **Rename...  F2** item in the **Edit** main menu is disabled at that time, which might be the reason that <kbd>F2</kbd>  does not work.

In short, I can rename an item from the side pane tree by selecting it, doing right click, and then choosing **Rename...**; however I would like the <kbd>F2</kbd> key to work on the  side pane tree too.

Thunar version is 4.17.9.

---

I created [an issue for this](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/-/issues/1085); but, I would like to know if a workaround is possible.

Comment: You may need to ask the developers to implement that. That would be a valid request for consistency. In the mean time, for keyboard access, you should be able to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, with the item selected, to access the right-click menu.

Comment: Ok then: https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/-/issues/1085